# smbclient gives error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND

Tags: file-sharing

I am running a Ubuntu in VirtaulBox and I am trying to connect to a shared folder on my windows using Samba. But I keep on getting the error message

> NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND

[image]

PS: I have enabled NetBIOS over TCP/IP on my windows